# Unit Test: Clone and equality

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am writing Unit Tests and thinking about the scenario of a type that implements `IClonable`.
So of course I want to have a Unit Test that tests the `Clone()` method.

```
[Test]
public void CloneObject()
{
    MyType original = new MyType();
    MyType clone = (MyType)original.Clone();

    // Assert for equality
}
```

So my first task it to have an `Assert` for the equality. I see following options:

- going through all properties (fields) of `MyType` and check them one by one
- override `Equals()` in `MyType` to let `MyType` say if two instances are equal (consider that sometimes equality for tests is considered different of equality for production code)
- Check with some kind of serialization if the instances are equal (for that scenario `MyType` would have to be `[Serializable]`, but that sometimes is hard to do if it has e.g. Interface Properties)
- ...??

For the first two I can setup my tests and they work well. But what if I change `MyType` and add an additional property? If `Clone()` doesn't copy this and I don't add it in the list of checked properties or the equals method my test still passes even if the property does not get copied.

How do you solve this kind of tests?

Comment: Have you considered Json (de)serialization or does that suffer from the same limitations as binary serialization (`[Serializable]`) in your view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki) library (a TDD must-have, IMO), which has a `ShouldBeEquivalent` method that performs [graph comparison](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison) of the two objects:

```
original.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(clone);
```

The comparison algorithm can be customized via the optional `options` parameter; see their [wiki](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison) for detailed info.

To make the test future-proof (i.e., it breaks when new properties are added to the class, but *not* to the `Clone` method), you might want to test cloning an object with all its properties set to random non-default values. [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) can do that for you.

```
// Arrange
var fixture = new Fixture();
var original = fixture.Create<MyType>();

// Act
var clone = original.Clone();

// Assert
clone.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(original);
```

Useful links:

- [FluentAssertions Cheat-Sheet](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki)
- [AutoFixture Cheat-Sheet](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet) (it's a bit outdated, but it demonstrates most of its basic features)

Comment: @joerg no prob! Be sure to check out what else you can do with FluentAssertions - it's full of goodies!

Comment: Oops... one step back... I just added an `int` to my type... I would have to set a non-default-value in my test to fail... just adding this property and the test still passes...

Comment: Thanks again :) Test PASSED... maybe I should start a new question with "What Frameworks do you need for UnitTests"... seems that you need quite a few

Comment: @joerg That question would be considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) though :P Discussing that on a [SO chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) might be a good idea though! I learned about those two very useful tools a while ago from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24922904/857807). Another useful tool is a decent mocking framework, in case you're not aware of those. I personally prefer Moq.

Answer (score 1):

I would favor implementing Equals().  I see no reason why Equals() needs to produce different results in production vs. in tests.

If you don't do that, your Assert could call object.ReferenceEquals(), as follows:

```
Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(expectedObject, objectInHand));
```

Comment: I found reading [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/06/22/Test-specificEqualityversusDomainEquality/) very helpful... the ReferenceEquals should Assert to false because the clone should have a different reference than the original